# How to get a full_html textarea field in a Drupal 8 configuration form?

Tags: drupal-8

In my module I have a configuration form (ConfigFormBase) with a simple textarea field without formatting that works correctly.

```
$form['page_message'] = [
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => $this->t('Message'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Message display to customer contacts.'),
  '#default_value' => $config->get('page_message'),
];
```

But I would like a textarea full_html field.

Is this possible and how with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but you have to do it like this:

```
$form['page_message'] = [
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#title' => $this->t('Message'),
  '#format' => 'full_html',
  '#description' => $this->t('Message display to customer contacts.'),
  '#default_value' => $config->get('page_message'),
];
```

You can check Drupal api for TextFormat.php [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21filter%21src%21Element%21TextFormat.php/8.5.x), just click on view source and you will have all the info you need.